# Patenting a doodling technique

Tags: us20060078855

In reference to the patent: [US20060078855](https://www.google.com/patents/US20060078855)

It appears this is attempting to patent the teaching procedure, however I have been doing this doodling these since well-before seeing the application.

In a case like this, the invention doesn't require someone to teach a person to do perform it, as it's straight-forward enough that anyone can figure it out.

How does the United States patent system respond to those circumstances? Furthermore, could I now be sued for infringing based off my own doodles?

Comment: Hello Swathi, and welcome to Ask Patents. I'm sorry to hear you're frustrated about this application. Being a [Q&A site](/tour), we do strive to keep questions as succinct as possible, so that content is brought forward to future readers with similar curiosities. I've taken the liberty of editing your question a bit, just to ensure our audience will get the most from it. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

US 2006/0078855 is not a patent.  It is only a published application.

One can view application file history with USPTO Public PAIR by searching on application number 11/229928.  In this case there has been a lengthy battle between the applicant and the USPTO.

Whether or not the applicant will be ever be successful in obtaining a patent and what the *claims* in any such patent might be are open questions at this point.

Comment: Heads up, in lieu of closing this, I edited the question pretty substantially. I tried to make it so your answer still applies, but I did bring to light some questions that the poster was originally trying to ask. It might not hurt for you to glance over the question and see whether there's anything you could add to this, although I'll leave that to your discretion for now.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen  I appreciate that you're trying to improve the quality of the question.  I think I'll just leave the answer as-is because I'm not sure what Swathi S's main concern is.